# MYSQL CURRENT_TIMESTAMP is 5-13 minutes off

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp

I have a mysql table that auto populates a timestamp using CURRENT_TIMESTAMP. I have a cron job that runs every 1 minute that populates the table with data. For some reason only on this table my time stamps are 5-13 minutes behind. I'm running php 7.1 with MYSQL 5.6.37. My other database tables populate the timestamp just fine and correct.  I've talked with my hosting company they have tried to sync WHM clocks we have restarted MYSQL but we haven't had any luck.

Example:
Timestamp from CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 2017-10-10 13:59:00
The correct time should be  2017-10-10 14:07:00

The bazaar thing is, sometimes its 5 minutes off all the way up to 13 minutes off.

Here is my query it inserts 197 records into my database

```
foreach ($coin_summary as $coin => $row) {

    $price_last = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$row['price_last']);
    $price_low  = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$row['price_low']);
    $price_high = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$row['price_high']);
    $volume     = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$row['volume']);
    $price_bid  = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$row['price_bid']);
    $price_ask  = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$row['price_ask']);
    $open_buy   = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$row['open_buy_orders']);
    $open_sell  = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$row['open_sell_orders']);

    // insert coin data into database
    $query = "
            INSERT INTO coin_data
                SET
                    coin_id = (SELECT id FROM crypto_coin WHERE coin_name = '$coin'),
                    price_last = '$price_last',
                    price_low = '$price_low',
                    price_high = '$price_high',
                    volume = '$volume',
                    price_bid = '$price_bid',
                    price_ask = '$price_ask',
                    open_buy_orders = '$open_buy',
                    open_sell_orders = '$open_sell'
            ";

    $con -> query($query);

}
```

Comment: I bet the cron job is running longer than you are expecting. If you run `select current_timestamp`, does it give the correct time?

Comment: There defiantly needs to be some php/mysql added to your question.  Say your CRON job starts at '13:00:00' you do something its running running running and then inserts 7 minutes later ... of course its going to be '13:07:00'.   Please update your question so we can help.

Comment: Yes I just did a query on select current_timestamp and its showing the correct time. This is a pretty small script and takes less then a second to finishes. If my cron job goes over 30 seconds, it would get time out by my server.

Comment: Cron jobs don't have the same sort of time out that web scripts do. You can try logging to a file or another table when the script runs and when it finishes, and see exactly how long it takes.

Comment: Even if I run the script manually by viewing the page it still puts in the wrong time stamps. I also deleted my cron job and recreated it, which I assume would clear out any pending crons. Still no luck.

Comment: have you tried adding the timestamp to your insert query ?

Comment: I just tried that and now it seems to be working.